# Diferenças de desempenho entre structs e classes

Tags: c++, classes, desempenho, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória

Sei que a diferença de `structs` e classes é que `structs` tem seus membros públicos por padrão, e que `structs` pertencem a C (mas nada impede de usar em C++).

Na prática quando se cria um objeto para classes ou uma estrutura, quem é o mais lento? Qual vai ocupar mais memória? Quem tem seu acesso mais rápido?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em C++ não há a menor diferença a não ser a já citada na pergunta, então não há como ter diferença de performance de qualquer tipo ou consumo de memória. Poderiam ter optado por não ter criado a palavra-chave `class` ou poderiam ter criado ela substituindo a `struct`, se não quisesse manter compatibilidade com C. Daria na mesma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entretanto, embora não tenha sido perguntado pelo OP existem diferenças entre as duas, por exemplo: structs não possuem construtores, não são considerados OO portanto não podem ter relacionamentos de herança, não podem possuir métodos, etc.

Comment: @Zorkind não pode? Pode discorrer sobre isto? E porque isto compila? https://ideone.com/LwcDwD E por que está nesta documentação? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: ok, me enganei sobre o construtor, por algum motivo tinha na cabeça que não podia, mas e quanto ao resto? :-)

Comment: Mesma coisa, tá tudo no *link* que eu passei.

Comment: Ah eu tava com C# na cabeça com relação a herança, desculpe https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct :-)

Comment: Porém de qualquer maneira os construtores em Struct funcionam de forma diferente de Classe então eu não estou totalmente errado hahahaha

Comment: C# permite construtores https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs

Comment: Em C++ é idêntico.

Comment: eu falei com relação a herança no doc que eu passei está claro que Struct não pode herdar de outro Struct em C# :-)

Comment: Outra fonte confirmando tudo que eu falei, não pode ter construtor default e não pode ter herança, em C# https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs

Comment: Structs e classes não têm diferença alguma além do modificador de acesso padrão. Em algumas implementações, não tem diferença nem pro linker.